# Connecting to database with Amundsen databuilder

Tags: database, metadata, data-warehouse

Dears
Recently I came across with issue while constructing the metadata solution - Amundsen for the enterprise DWH. with the below mentioned github repository everything went well. But, unfortunately I unable to connect to the database with Amundsen databuilder.
I have entered all the credentials and IP of data source to the respective loader files
from the amundsen\databuilder\example\scripts folder.

Could you please advice any suggestions for connecting to the database?

https://github.com/amundsen-io/amundsen/blob/main/docs/installation.md#bootstrap-a-default-
version-of-amundsen-using-docker